# pg_search gem returns duplicates

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, pg-search

I am using the [pg_search gem](https://github.com/Casecommons/pg_search) to search within a model and noticed certain searches return repeats of the same result.

```
class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
    include PgSearch::Model
    pg_search_scope :client_search, 
        against: [:name, :mindbody_id, :phone, :unique_mb], 
        associated_against: {
            address: [:phone, :street],
            user: [:email],
            location: [:name]
        },
        using: { 
            tsearch: { 
                prefix: true 
            }
        }
   ...
end
```

When I search `Client.client_search("abc")`, my resulting array contains the same `Client` many times.  Each entry has the same ID and the results seem indistinguishable.

Any idea why the result is duplicating?

Comment: The issue was that the `client` in question had 5 `addresses` when they should have only had 1 resulting in the duplication.

Answer (score 0):

You need to move the `against` part into `associated_against` as searching columns on the associated models.

```
pg_search_scope :client_search,
  associated_against: {
    client:   [:name, :mindbody_id, :phone, :unique_mb],
    address:  [:phone, :street],
    user:     [:email],
    location: [:name]
  },
  using: { 
    tsearch: { 
      prefix: true 
    }
  }
...
```

Comment: I get an error after making that change: `NoMethodError (undefined method 'table_name' for nil:NilClass)`